# Subscribe pattern Redis with Python

Tags: python, redis, publish-subscribe

I am trying develop a notifications system based on Python and Redis. I have been checking the python `redis` [module](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py#publish--subscribe) and I saw a small pattern subscribe example:

```
p.psubscribe('my-*', ...)
```

Theorically, that is the way, so I tried something similar

```
import redis
import time

r =redis.StrictRedis(host = 'localhost', port=6379, db=0)
p = r.pubsub()
p.psubscribe('*')

for msg in p.listen():
    print time.time(), msg
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

I am trying subscribe to every keys to made the example easiest. However, I only get this message at the first, and while I am changing the key's values I get nothing else.

```
1479469808.51 {'pattern': None, 'type': 'psubscribe', 'channel': '*', 'data': 1L}
```

I can see that `pattern` is None, so I understand that I am not really subscribing. How deal I with it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a very simple mistake. The code worked well, but I have had to execute the following command in Redis

```
config set notify-keyspace-events KEA
```